# MSDTC on SQL Server 2012 with mount point for data disk

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, msdtc

I have installed a new SQL Server 2012 instance on a cluster. The installation went fine but when I've added the MSDTC as resource of the instance, it went wrong. When I just added it, the MSDTC was online but when I tried my first failover, it refused to go online. The error message was "MSDTC failed".

My configuration is:
a physical drive disk (let say J:) with two mount points "DATA" and "LOG".

I read some people who experienced this kind of errors with mount points and SQL Server 2008 but nothing with 2012.

I tried to create the "MSDTC" folder on the physical drive (the J: one) but nothing better.

Does anyone know something about it or know how to configure the MSDTC and force it to use the J: drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When parametrized, the dependency disk is the disk on which the msdtc will create its directories. This disk must NOT be a mount point.

Hope it can help someone